# Scraping Airbnb data - Beautifulsoup output to csv file

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup

Right now I have a script that can print out basic info on Airbnb listings based on a specified URL:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

headers = {'User-Agent':'Google Chrome, Windows 10'}

url = 'https://www.airbnb.com/s/Tokyo--Japan/homes?tab_id=home_tab&refinement_paths%5B%5D=%2Fhomes&flexible_trip_dates%5B%5D=april&flexible_trip_dates%5B%5D=may&flexible_trip_lengths%5B%5D=weekend_trip&date_picker_type=calendar&checkin=2021-04-09&checkout=2021-04-23&adults=3&source=structured_search_input_header&search_type=autocomplete_click&query=Tokyo%2C%20Japan&place_id=ChIJ51cu8IcbXWARiRtXIothAS'

response = requests.get(url,headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content,'lxml')

for item in soup.select('[itemprop=itemListElement]'):
    try:
        print('----------------------------------------')
        print(item.select('a')[0]['aria-label']) #Title
        print(item.select('a')[0]['href']) #URL
        print(item.select('._krjbj')[0].get_text()) #Price
        print(item.select('._krjbj')[2].get_text()) #Total price

        print(item.select('._kqh46o')[0].get_text()) #Facilities
        print(item.select('._kqh46o')[1].get_text()) #Amenities
        print(item.select('._18khxk1')[0].get_text()) #Rating with number of reviews in parentheses

        # print(name)

        print('----------------------------------------')
    except Exception as e:
        #raise e
        print('')
```

I'd like output for this stored in a csv. Here's an attempt using BeautifulSoup:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

headers = {'User-Agent':'Google Chrome, Windows 10'}

f = csv.writer(open('airbnbscraping.csv', 'w'))
f.writerow(["title", "weburl", "nightprice", "totalprice", "facilities", "amenities", "ratings"])

for item in soup.select('[itemprop=itemListElement]'):
    try:
        title = item.select(('a')[0]['aria-label'])
        weburl = item.select(('a')[0]['href'])
        nightprice = str(('._krjbj')[0].get_text())
        totalprice = str(('._krjbj')[2].get_text())

        facilities = str(('._kqh46o')[0].get_text())
        amenities = str(('._kqh46o')[1].get_text())
        ratings = str(('._18khxk1')[0].get_text())

    except Exception as e:
        # raise e
        continue

    f.writerow([title, weburl, nightprice, totalprice, facilities, amenities, ratings])
```

Currently only the header row is written to the csv...how could I get the desired values into the table as well? Would I have to use `.find` and `.find_all` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a context manager to handle the file open/write and re-work some of your selectors.

Move the `try except` to where it actually needs to handle the current exception.

Please note that the classes look dynamic so scraping using current classes is not particularly robust. I would instead look for relationships between more stable looking elements/attributes.

I also needed to change your user-agent to one the server was happy with otherwise only the header would be written due to no results from the initial `soup.select` used for the loop.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}
url = 'https://www.airbnb.com/s/Tokyo--Japan/homes?tab_id=home_tab&refinement_paths%5B%5D=%2Fhomes&flexible_trip_dates%5B%5D=april&flexible_trip_dates%5B%5D=may&flexible_trip_lengths%5B%5D=weekend_trip&date_picker_type=calendar&checkin=2021-04-09&checkout=2021-04-23&adults=3&source=structured_search_input_header&search_type=autocomplete_click&query=Tokyo%2C%20Japan&place_id=ChIJ51cu8IcbXWARiRtXIothAS'
response = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content,'lxml')

with open("airbnbscraping.csv", "w", encoding="utf-8-sig", newline='') as f:
   
    w = csv.writer(f, delimiter = ",", quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    w.writerow(["title", "weburl", "nightprice", "totalprice", "facilities", "amenities", "ratings"])

    for item in soup.select('[itemprop=itemListElement]'):
   
        title = item.select_one('._8s3ctt a')['aria-label']
        weburl = 'https://www.airbnb.co.uk/' + item.select_one('a')['href']
        nightprice = item.select_one('._olc9rf0').text
        totalprice = item.select_one('button span:contains("total")').text.split(' ')[0]
        facilities = item.select_one('._kqh46o').get_text()
        amenities = item.select_one('[itemprop=itemListElement] ._kqh46o + ._kqh46o').get_text()
        try:
            ratings = item.select_one('._10fy1f8').text
        except:
            ratings = 'None'
        
        w.writerow([title, weburl, nightprice, totalprice, facilities, amenities, ratings])
```

Comment: Didn't think that it would be the user-agent value causing the blank rows - thanks for your help on this!

Comment: hi, I have the same problem as the question asked and I tried your answer, but it doesn't work. Do you have an idea why? It tells me "KeyError: 'aria-label'